# SQL Server Changing Column Data Type for Multiple Tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

We are going through our database (SQL Server 2014) and doing some normalization. The database has been migrated from MS Access gradually over years by many different people and unfortunately columns are not standard across all tables. I built the script below trying to do it automatedly because there are many tables. I keep hitting wall after wall. The last wall I am hitting and having a hard time overcoming is this:
[image]
A couple notes about this script:

1. It contains a table called ColumnModel which holds the column name and the datatype we want to convert the column to.
2. So far I have ran two other scripts against the database trying to get this to work. The first script removed all constraints. The second script was supposed to remove all indexes from all tables but I keep hitting the error pictured above.

   ```
   DECLARE @Tables TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(200))
   DECLARE @Columns TABLE (ColumnName VARCHAR(200))
   DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(200)
   DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(200)
   DECLARE @NewDataType AS VARCHAR(200)
   DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(500)
   DECLARE @Nullable AS BIT

   INSERT INTO @Tables
   SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS TableName FROM sys.columns c
   INNER JOIN sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
   INNER JOIN ColumnModel cm ON '['+ c.name+ ']' = cm.[Column]
   ORDER BY o.name

   SELECT @TableName= MIN(TableName) FROM @Tables
   WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN

   INSERT INTO @Columns
   SELECT c.name AS ColumnName FROM sys.columns c
   INNER JOIN sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
   INNER JOIN ColumnModel cm ON '['+ c.name+ ']' = cm.[Column]
   WHERE o.name =  @TableName 
   ORDER BY c.name

       -- LOOP THROUGH EACH COLUMN IN TABLE AND MODIFY DATATYPE
   SELECT @ColumnName= MIN(ColumnName) FROM @Columns
   WHILE @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
       -- DETERMINE IF Column Is Nullable or not
       SET @Nullable = (SELECT c.is_nullable FROM sys.columns c
                       INNER JOIN sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
                       INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                       INNER JOIN ColumnModel cm ON '['+ c.name+ ']' = cm.[Column]
                       WHERE o.name =  @TableName AND c.name =  @ColumnName)

       -- GET New Data Type
       SET @NewDataType = (SELECT DataType FROM ColumnModel WHERE [Column] =  '['+ @ColumnName+ ']')
       IF @Nullable = 1
       BEGIN
           SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.[' + @TableName + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + @ColumnName + '] ' + @NewDataType + ' NULL'
           EXEC(@SQL)
           PRINT @SQL
       END

       IF @Nullable = 0
       BEGIN
           -- ALTER COLUMN
           SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.[' + @TableName + ']  ALTER COLUMN [' + @ColumnName + '] ' + @NewDataType + ' NOT NULL'
           EXEC(@SQL)
           PRINT @SQL
       END
      DELETE FROM @Columns
       -- MOVE NEXT COLUMN
       SELECT @ColumnName = MIN(ColumnName) FROM @Columns  WHERE  ColumnName > @ColumnName
   END

   -- MOVE NEXT TABLE
   SELECT @TableName = MIN(TableName) FROM @Tables  WHERE  TableName > @TableName
   ```

   END

**REMOVE ALL DB Indexes Script:**

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) + ' ON ' +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' DISABLE' 
FROM sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND I.name IS NOT NULL
AND I.is_disabled = 0
```

The Drop and Create all Constraints script I captured from here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/

The only modification being that I created a local table instead of a table variable. However this script generated all of the Drop code in one column and all of the create code in another column... instead of adding it to rows. Do you think it's possible that the columns couldn't hold the full script? The column didn't seem to be truncated so I thought this wasn't an issue.

In both of these scripts I copied the dynamically created code and executed it manually.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the scripts you haven't shown us...

Comment: It seems the other scripts missed some indexes and constraints.

Comment: @IanKemp Thank you for the response, see updated answer.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for the response, see updated answer.

Comment: The "drop" index script doesn't drop them, it only disables them. It also doesn't touch clustered indexes,

Comment: I would be very careful doing that with a self written script. There are database managment tools that can help you with that out there in a safe way - though they might not be free to use (perhaps a trial version?)